# A range joined with a formula with colons

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, syntax, count, google-sheets-formula

I have this Google Sheets formula that I encountered in this answers here
[answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74267796/google-translate-internal-error-when-using-the-googletranslate-function-in-goo/74267955#comment131119865_74267955), [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74280580/19529694), and I couldn't find the support page for it of Google Sheets.

In layman's terms, please explain how this works.

```
=A5:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A))
```

[image: i1]

---

| Values | Formula |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | 36 |
| 42 | 19 |
| 12 | 26 |
| 36 | 10 |
| 19 |  |
| 26 |  |
| 10 |  |

I was provided with this [refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74279873/stacking-multiple-arrays-in-query-lambda-function/74280580?noredirect=1#comment131141196_74280580) to this excel's [support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculation-operators-and-precedence-in-excel-48be406d-4975-4d31-b2b8-7af9e0e2878a) by the [@TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

based on your image...

```
=A5:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A))
```

is literally translatable as

```
=A5:A8
```

where `A5:` is start of the range `INDEX(A2:A` is column of the range end, and  `COUNTA(A2:A)` counts how many cells are not empty in range A2:A

| formula | transcript |
| --- | --- |
| =A5: | =A5: |
| INDEX(A2:A, | A |
| COUNTA(A2:A)) | 8 |

note that standalone `=COUNTA(A2:A)` results in `7` but within the formula its `8` due to INDEX being offset

while it is short it is not reliable in case there are empty cells within A2:A range. therefore it is recommended to use:

```
=A5:INDEX(A:A, MAX((A:A<>"")*ROW(A:A)))
```

it's a choice of preference but the above is same as:

```
=INDIRECT("A5:A"&MAX((A:A<>"")*ROW(A:A)))
```