# My ArrayFormula with SUM and non-contiguous fields is not calculating correct totals per row

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a spreadsheet (Google Sheets) with several non-contiguous Cost columns. When I try to user ArrayFormula to sum each row "Grand Total", it's returning some interesting (incorrect) numbers.

Here's a sample, stripped down the number of cost columns for brevity.

| Venue Cost | Moving | Moving Details | AV Support | Grand Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1500 | 500 |  | 500 | 2500 |
| 2500 | 500 |  | 750 | 3750 |
| 1500 | 500 |  | 500 | 2500 |

My Array Formula for the Grand Total Column is

`=ARRAYFORMULA(filter(G2:G, G2:G<>"") + SUM(H2:H,J2:J))`

where G is the Venue Cost and H and J are additional costs.

This is the resulting Grand Total:

| Venue Cost | Moving | Moving Details | AV Support | Grand Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1500 | 500 |  | 500 | 4750 |
| 2500 | 500 |  | 750 | 5750 |
| 1500 | 500 |  | 500 | 4750 |

I tried moving away from SUM, to just manually adding the additional costs together.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(filter(G2:G, G2:G<>"") + (J2:J + H2:H ))`

but received the #N/A error, which expanded to "Error: Array arguments to ADD are of different size." We have a document generating tool that sees those N/A's as additional jobs to process, so any extra spillover is not good:

| Venue Cost | Moving | Moving Details | AV Support | Grand Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1500 | 500 |  | 500 | 2500 |
| 2500 | 500 |  | 750 | 3750 |
| 1500 | 500 |  | 500 | 2500 |
|  |  |  |  | #N/A |
|  |  |  |  | #N/A |

I'm pretty sure that the SUM and the ADD versions are including more than one row, do I need to filter the 'Additional Costs' Columns as well as the Venue Costs? Or, are the non-contiguous columns an issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(G2:G="",,G2:G+H2:H+J2:J))
```

or:

```
=BYROW({G2:H, J2:J}, LAMBDA(x, SUM(x)))
```

or:

```
=BYROW({G2:H, J2:J}, LAMBDA(x, IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(x)))))
```

or:

```
=BYROW({G2:INDEX(H:H, COUNTA(G:G)), J2:INDEX(J:J, COUNTA(G:G))}, LAMBDA(x, SUM(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks, @player0! Thanks, @player0!  I tried Example 2:  Calculations were correct, but provided empty 0's in all the empty rows.  

Example 3 provides the desired result, but I'd like to understand it more.  Previously, if I was using an array formula in a column, it's in the second row, and all of my column references begin at CxR2.  This formula uses both R2 and just the column identifier. 
Is that intentional?  THANKS!

Comment: @LoreBurek answer updated. try 3rd formula and for understanding 4th formula see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74281216/5632629

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understand what you're trying to accomplish, but try this:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(G2:G="","",G2:G+H2:H+J2:J))