# Calculate the average of sets of cells satisfying a certain criterion (AVERAGEIF)

Tags: google-sheets, filter, lambda, average, google-query-language

This is my Items sheet

[image]

And this is my Values sheet

[image]

As can be seen from the table, *alfa* is associated with 20 40 60 80, *beta* with 30 40 70 80 and *gamma* with 50 60 70 80.

In the Items sheet in cell B1 (next to the first item) I would like a formula (Arrayformula or alike) generating the average value for each item. In my example it should be:

```
alfa -> 50 (that is: (20+40+60+80)/4 = 200/4)  
beta -> 55 (that is: (30+40+70+80)/4 = 220/4)  
gamma-> 65 (that is: (50+60+70+80)/4 = 260/4)
```

So the final result should be:

[image]

This is my googlesheet: [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zFOMIo8JB-rMI74ATv3233KzNk176rcc0caX7GuNoj4/edit?usp=sharing)

P.S. For simplicity's sake, I used just columns A:C for items in Values sheet. In real case I have 10 columns so I want to avoid to specify each one in the formula and instead use a range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=BYROW(A1:A3, LAMBDA(x, INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Values!A1:C10&"​"&Values!D1:D10), "​"), 
 "select avg(Col2) where Col1 = '"&x&"'"), 2)))
```

[image]

---

### update

```
=IFERROR(BYROW(A1:INDEX(A:A, MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""))), 
 LAMBDA(x, INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 FILTER(Values!A:C, Values!D:D<>"")&"​"&
 FILTER(Values!D:D, Values!D:D<>"")), "​"),   
 "select avg(Col2) where Col1 = '"&x&"'"), 2))))
```

Comment: I tried to modify your formula avoiding the row number like this: `FLATTEN(Values!A1:C&"​"&Values!D1:D)` but it doesn't work. Is there any easy way to make it work?

Comment: @G.Lari try: `=BYROW(A1:A3, LAMBDA(x, INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Values!A1:C&"​"&Values!D1:D), "​"), 
 "select avg(Col2) where Col1 = '"&x&"'"), 2)))`

Comment: Programming is never boring..... just joking. Yes @player0 your code works. What I tried that didn't work was this `=BYROW(A1:A, LAMBDA(x, INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Values!A1:C&"​"&Values!D1:D), "​"),   "select avg(Col2) where Col1 = '"&x&"'"), 2)))`. I simply changed the range at beginning `A1:A`. Doing so googlesheet takes many minutes to calculate the formula.

Comment: @G.Lari answer updated. use 2nd formula

Comment: It looks working fantastically well.  Many thanks @player0!!!!! P.S. Now I study your answer :)

Comment: @G.Lari try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74393500/5632629 and: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74281216/5632629

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249862/discussion-between-g-lari-and-player0).