# how could I count minus cells in a column excluding the last one?

Tags: google-sheets, countif

[image]

I want to count on another sheet that how many people have a minus balance. Of course, I should use `COUNTIF`, but how could I dynamically narrow the range from `C2` to the second last non-blank cell(because there's a chance for the total balance to be minus, it should be excluded)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:INDEX(C2:C,COUNTA(C2:C)-1),"<0")
```

- Here `C2:INDEX(C2:C,COUNTA(C2:C)-1)` will return a array of values as well cell reference from **C2** to last second non empty cell in column C (Assume you do not have any blank rows inside data). If you have blank row, then you have to use different approach. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/5514747) by @TheMaster
- `COUNTA(C2:C)` will count all non blank cells in C column then minus `1` from that count to make it second non empty cell till down to up.
- And then apply `COUNTIFS()` function.

[image]

Comment: Is there any official document telling why the return value of `INDEX` could be used in the cell reference, i.e. `C2:INDEX(...)`?

Comment: Besides, could the column letter also be referred in a similar way without the use of `INDIRECT`? I have tried `A1:ADDRESS(2,2)` but it does not work.

Comment: I do not look for official documentation for this but there are lot of post around blogs regarding this specially volatile vs non volatile functions. In stack-overflow there are many post.

Comment: @idfurw https://stackoverflow.com/a/74281216/5632629

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd